# How to align input boxes center?

Tags: html, css

I have difficulty trying to put the input boxes for a form in the middle of the form, they don't seem to get affected by justify-content and align-items

(This question has been asked before, but I don't use labels, so the answers don't seem to work for me)

```css
.form_exterior{
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.grid_form{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.form_title{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section_button_form{
  text-align: center;
}

.form_boxes{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <article class="form_exterior">
          <form class="form_items">
            <section class="grid_form">

            <h1 class="form_title">Personal Information</h1>
            <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="name" value="Name">
            <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="last name" value="Last name">
            <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="email" value="Email">
            <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="phone number" value="Phone number">

            <h1 class="form_title">Shipping information</h1>
            <select class="form_boxes" id="country" name="Select country">
              <option>select country</option>
              <option value="US">United States</option>
              <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
              
              <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="city" value="City">
              <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="postal code" value="Postal code">
              <input class="form_boxes" type="text" name="street" value="Street address">
            </select>
            <section class="section_button_form">
              <button onclick="alertForm()" class="button_form" type="button" name="order_button">order</button>
              <a href="Webshop.html"><button class="button_form" type="button" name="go_back_button">go back</button></a>
            </section>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>
```

Comment: `<input>` inside a `<select>`? Just no. Invalid HTML. Fix your markup first, than you can play with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, it might save your issue:

```
.grid_form{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 justify-items : center;
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work, but after also fixing the errors in my html (non closed tags, input in selects) mentioned by Roko it did work, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe your input boxes are block level elements and therefore are referenced to the width of their container.

You can set the width in your input element.

[: The Input (Form Input) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

You could also try changing the display attribute on your input box to display: inline-block.
You might need to set a min-width on those elements also.